# substring replacement regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

Add a semicolon (;) to the end of every line.

This is what I have:
([^\n])$

The problem is it takes the last characther out instead of adding the semicolon on the end.

Also, I am using Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here your pattern is intentional, in that you only want to match line-endings of non-empty lines. (If you want to match all lines, simply remove the `([^\n])`)

In the `Replace with` field you need to write back the match character:

```
$1;
```

Obviously, your match is replaced, so if you match a character before the end of line, it's going to be replaced. But if you wrap it in parentheses (like you did), it's *captured* and can be referred to in the replacement string.

Alternatively, you can use a *lookbehind*, which checks the condition but does *not* include its contents in the match:

```
(?<=[^\n])$
```

This way, you can simply replace with `;`. In your case it doesn't really make a difference. In performance-critical scripts with more complicated expressions, capturing tends to be an expensive operation, so that lookarounds are often favorable.

Comment: While I have your attention could you help me with this?

Comment: @BobSmithsfield with what?

Comment: Replace any pattern in the form of [__CHARACTERS__] with (characters)
[__SOMEDATA__] becomes (somedata)

This is what I have: \[__\w+__\]

My main problem is it grabs the word but I dont know how to make it change to lower case without the ___ maybe I am not using the correct replace statement or something.

Comment: @BobSmithsfield this is not the place to discuss this, but I've answered your other question regarding this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find: \r\n
replace: ;\r\n
```

In windows files, the common newline is CRLF (\r\n)

or

```
find: (.)(\r\n|$)
replace: $1;$2
```

to avoid to put ; in blank lines and to put it on the last line